# Custom Pagination Layout for Elementor widget

Tags: wp-query, pagination

My homepage consists of various Elementor widgets showing blog posts. Each of this widget is a custom WordPress query. I was able to make pagination work for each of this widget, but it loads the same homepage with all other widgets, so I have to scroll to the widget that I clicked.

What I'm trying to achieve is when I click on 2nd page in pagination, it loads completely different layout only with 2nd page posts of this particular widget. The perfect example would be -
https://demo.tagdiv.com/newspaper/ If you scroll down to LATEST ARTICLES and click 2nd page it loads new page with posts.

I found the way of how to load different template in pagination using this filter:

```
function my_second_main_template($template){
    if (is_front_page() && is_paged()){
         $alternate_template = locate_template( 'paginated.php');
         if(!empty($alternate_template))
              $template =$alternate_template;
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','my_second_main_template');
```

In **paginated.php** I'm using custom query to fetch the latest posts:

```
<?php
     $paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

     $query = new WP_Query([
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
         'paged' => $paged;
         'posts_per_page' => 3 // this must be dynamic
     ]);


     if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post() ?>

         <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() ); ?>


<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Now I need to find the way of how to get the number of posts that's been set in the widget on the homepage. Which is controlled by **post_items** setting and it's dynamic and controlled by Elementor plugin. So to get the setting in Elementor widget I use

```
public function get_post_items() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
    $output = $settings['post_items'];
    return $output;
}
```

When I try to access this property outside of Elementor plugin I get Fatal error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Elementor\Controls_Stack::sanitize_settings() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\MAMP\htdocs\wp_neotech\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php on line 1018 and defined in C:\MAMP\htdocs\wp_neotech\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\base\controls-stack.php:1953
```

When I try to access the same setting in the widget Class itself, it works fine. My guess that when I instantiate the widget class, **get_settings_for_display()** is not yet ready, hence can't be accessed yet.

Comment: How did you manage to bring several pages into one page?

Comment: you need to ask this in an Elementor community, 3rd party plugin dev support questions are not in this stacks scope and offtopic here